# `pathPaymentStrictSend` transaction produces error `op_under_dest_min` howmuchever the `destMin`

Tags: horizon, path-payment, paths

Recreate this transaction on the Stellar laboratory (view XDR to see parameters):

```
AAAAAJ2XxPOBZhImQhYvufkgoiaUvlcAA3oYpZpxw4uO/3GeAAAAZAGEyw0AAAsBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAA0AAAABVVNEAAAAAADophqGHmCvYPgHc+BjRuXHLL5Z3K3aN2CNWO9CUR2f3AAAAAAAAAPoAAAAAJ2XxPOBZhImQhYvufkgoiaUvlcAA3oYpZpxw4uO/3GeAAAAAA3gtrOmy2mAAAAAAQAAAAFCVEMAAAAAAGrl+/NlIBMvk84azG8w7Y0MFeUfapja8f6qDe6lavWuAAAAAAAAAAGO/3GeAAAAQJitSo00BJq46wFO3OYd+Qm9PI90zfjqoT1refqi/QeCcZY9cZm2BXtUL6r9zekDQOlsn7a954BT2h4C2Kj/Ewc=
```

Regardless of the `destMin` (Minimum destination amount) I enter, `0.0000001` or `99999999999`, I receive the error `op_under_dest_min`.

I tried a similar transaction with a `pathPaymentStrictReceive` transaction, and it went well.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the path. When one queries `https://horizon.stellar.org/paths/strict-send?source_asset_type=native&source_amount=.0008&destination_assets=USD:GDUKMGUGDZQK6YHYA5Z6AY2G4XDSZPSZ3SW5UN3ARVMO6QSRDWP5YLEX&c=0.04171017617619466` for example, the `destination_amount` is quite too big and it is the same in all the entries, and when one uses the first path for example to `send path payment strict send`, the same error above returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We think this may be a result of [Strict-send pathfinder returns non-existent paths](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/1856), which is fixed in [Horizon 0.23](https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/horizon-v0.23.0). Would you try the new release and report back here?

Comment: How does one try this new release? I am merely querying using my browser.

Comment: Well, you could download it and try it out. Or wait until SDF deploys it, which will be on 2019-11-19 and then query horizon.stellar.org after that.

Comment: 0.23 is now up. And I now can carry out the transaction as expected.